# In Node.js, is it possible to run a middleware function asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I've built a middleware function to validate user access tokens (JWT) ... if the JWT has expired, I automatically create a new access token from the user's refresh token (if it as well is valid, of course).

I imagine that at some point, if I have enough users, authorization could be a bottleneck. I'd like to ensure these functions are running asynchronously (e.g. via the UV threadpool).

Is this possible, or do I even have to worry about this?

ADDENDUM:

This is the decryption routine I'm using in my middleware function. I'm also using jsonwebtoken.

```
'use strict';

const cryptoAsync = require('@ronomon/crypto-async');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const util = require('util');

class AES {
    constructor(key, iv, bitSize) {
      // supported stream ciphers:
      // aes-256-ctr (keySize=32, ivSize=16)
      // aes-192-ctr (keySize=24, ivSize=16)
      // aes-128-ctr (keySize=16, ivSize=16)

      if (!bitSize) bitSize = 128;

      if (bitSize !== 256 && bitSize !== 192 && bitSize !== 128) {
        throw new Error('AES requires a bitsize of 256, 192, or 128.');
      }

      if (!key || key.length !== bitSize/8) throw new Error(`A ${bitSize/8}-byte/${bitSize}-bit key is required.`);

      if (!iv || iv.length !== 16) throw new Error('A 16-byte/128-bit initialization vector is required.');

      this.algo = `aes-${bitSize}-ctr`;
      this.key = key;
      this.iv = iv;

      console.log(`Using the ${this.algo} algorithm ...`);
    }
 
    async encrypt(dataAsUtf8) {
        const cipherText = await util.promisify(cryptoAsync.cipher)(this.algo, 1, this.key, this.iv, Buffer.from(dataAsUtf8, 'utf8'));

        return cipherText.toString('hex');
    }

    async decrypt(dataAsHex) {
    if (!Buffer.isEncoding('hex')) throw new Error('Input must be in HEX format.');

        const cipherText = await util.promisify(cryptoAsync.cipher)(this.algo, 0, this.key, this.iv, Buffer.from(dataAsHex, 'hex'));

        return cipherText.toString('utf8');
    }

    static randomBytes = async bytes => {
        const bytesAsBuffer = await util.promisify(crypto.randomBytes)(bytes);

    return bytesAsBuffer;
    }
}

module.exports = AES;
```

Comment: In Node.js, "asynchronous" normally refers to not blocking the main thread of execution. If your function is waiting on some asynchronous API, you're fine, the main thread is not blocked. Other requests process while you're waiting for that API to invoke a callback, resolve a promise, etc. However, I think the real issue might be that you are actually talking about *synchronous* code here - code that just "crunches math" and might take long enough to be a problem. Is that what's going on?

Comment: Express middlewares are designed to be capable of asynchronous execution. But I think you have a big misunderstanding of what asynchronous is. Asynchronous functions in node.js does not necessarily run in a separate thread let alone a thread pool. Especially if that asynchronous operation is network related

Comment: Yes, b/c my middleware is decrypting the JWT and checking its signature for validity. I'm just worried that these processes could be synchronous. I'm using the "jsonwebtoken" lib for signature validation, however for decryption, I'm using the @ronomon/crypto-async lib. (see addendum).

Comment: slebetman, maybe I don't understand async. then, you're right. How would async code run if it weren't in a separate thread? I understand about not needing the thread pool as network ops. use OS calls, but not sure I understand how Node.js runs async. code otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually pretty hard to write code that blocks the main thread in Node for a significant time unless you are doing some seriously heavy lifting, such as generating very large reports or the like. Authorization via JWT tokens is totally lightweight and will not be a problem, I can virtually guarantee that. You will not need to push that type of work off onto a separate thread, if that was the plan.